# Errors with a toast on a calculator app

Tags: java, android, calculator, toast

I'm struggling with a toast to overcome the empty editText problem.
No syntax errors but the app stops unexpectedly.

I'm not sure whether the problem comes from the listener or the IF loop. But the calculator works fine apart from the empty editText exception.

Thanks !!

Here is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.rayana.calculator.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:text="Result ="
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
        android:text="B =" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="A =" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="-" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="+" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:text="x" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
        android:text="÷" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Main.java:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    Button plus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button minus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button multiply = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button devide = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);




    plus.setOnClickListener(Operation1);
    minus.setOnClickListener(Operation1);
    multiply.setOnClickListener(Operation1);
    devide.setOnClickListener(Operation1);

 }
         ///Your click listener method:
 OnClickListener Operation1 = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            final EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

            final EditText editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

            final EditText editText3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);          

            if(editText1.getText().equals("") || editText2.getText().equals(""))  
            {
                 //toast the error message
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Please enter the numbers !";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
                 return;
            }
            else
            {
                final double A = Double.valueOf(editText1.getText().toString());
                final double B = Double.valueOf(editText2.getText().toString());
                switch(v.getId()){

                case R.id.button1:

                    double result = A+B;
                    editText3.setText(String.valueOf(result));
                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                    double result2 = A-B;
                    editText3.setText(String.valueOf(result2));
                    break;
                case R.id.button3:
                    double result3 = A*B;
                    editText3.setText(String.valueOf(result3));
                    break;
                case R.id.button4:
                    double result4 = A/B;
                    editText3.setText(String.valueOf(result4));
                    break;
                }
            }

            }
    };


}
```

and my Logcat:

```
11-07 15:32:43.518: V/TLINE(364): new: android.text.TextLine@40685a60
11-07 15:32:43.877: V/TLINE(364): new: android.text.TextLine@406920b0
11-07 15:32:45.847: D/AndroidRuntime(364): Shutting down VM
11-07 15:32:45.847: W/dalvikvm(364): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
11-07 15:32:45.887: E/AndroidRuntime(364): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-07 15:32:45.887: E/AndroidRuntime(364): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
11-07 15:32:45.887: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.invalidReal(FloatingPointParser.java:78)
11-07 15:32:45.887: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:276)
11-07 15:32:45.887: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:317)
11-07 15:32:45.887: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:354)
11-07 15:32:45.887: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at com.rayana.calculator2.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:62)
11-07 15:32:45.887: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3100)
11-07 15:32:45.887: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11644)
11-07 15:32:45.887: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-07 15:32:45.887: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-07 15:32:45.887: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
11-07 15:32:45.887: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
11-07 15:32:45.887: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 15:32:45.887: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
11-07 15:32:45.887: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
11-07 15:32:45.887: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
11-07 15:32:45.887: E/AndroidRuntime(364):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-07 15:32:46.017: D/dalvikvm(364): GC_CONCURRENT freed 193K, 5% free 6460K/6791K, paused 4ms+12ms
```

Comment: Since **"" can't be converted to any number**, can't you simply `if(editText1.getText().equals(""){editText1.setText"0")}` and same for the other EditText?

Comment: Check value of edit text if its null or string is empty, Then you may try to wrap it in try catch block if it fails set defaul value or focus on that edit text so user will provide correct value

Comment: @user3455363 Take a look at my answer. I have a feeling that my guess is correct :)

Comment: But if A or B = 0, shouldn't return any zeros as it's a calculator ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to :

```
if(editText1.getText().toString().equals("") || editText2.getText().toString().equals(""))
```

My guess is you forget to add `toString` so the `equals` method give the wrong result, **hence** your code go to the `else` statement and the `NumberFormatException` happened there (because "" is **not** a `Double`).

Comment: Ah perfect! It works ! So simple though ... I wonder how did I not see it ! Thank you ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that value inside editText1 or editText2 is not a valid double value.

You should surround those lines:

```
            final double A = Double.valueOf(editText1.getText().toString());
            final double B = Double.valueOf(editText2.getText().toString());
```

With try/catch block, for example:

```
try{
     final double A = Double.valueOf(editText1.getText().toString());
    final double B = Double.valueOf(editText2.getText().toString());
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
    //invalid double value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your error happens at `com.rayana.calculator2.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:62)`

which has the following command at it `double result = A+B;`

there are not the doubles you are looking for